# Summing the results of a lookup when the function arguments contain functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

my question is pretty specific, and I haven't been able to find a solution. Here's a sample dataset that illustrates the problem:

```
First     Last     Sales     Months
Kevin     Smith    $500      10
Joe       Stevens  $400      6
Frank     Doe      $600      4
```

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve any computation columns or cells in the final result.

Now lets say I had this list

```
Kevin Smith
Frank Doe
```

I want to sum their sales/month in a separate cell.

I've tried:

> =SUM(SUMIF(CONCATENATE(First, " ", Last),FullNames,Sales/Month))

Data is stored in rows 1-3 where column A is first name, Column B is last name, Column C is sales, and column D is months. The full names are in A5 and A6.

When I apply the function I have tried both *Enter* and *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*

Strangely enough, this formula works:

> =SUM(SUMIF(First,FirstNameSubSet,Sales))

When I don't do any array concatenation or division in the formula.

Unfortunately, in my real life problem, I can't use this workaround.

I tried posting a picture, but even though I've been reading the answers on this site for a long time, I've never posted anything so I have no 'reputation.'

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler if the full name were also in two separate cells.  You could use a simple SUMIFS.  But for the problem you present, if I understand it, given the following:

- `First` is the named range containing the first names
- `Last` is the named range containing the last names
- `Sales` is the named range containing the Sales amounts
- `Month` is the named range containing the number of months.
- `Fullnames` is the named range containing the full name (combined first and last name)

Then the following array-entered formula (formula entered by holding down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `enter`) should produced the sales per month

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sales,First,LEFT(FullNames,FIND(" ",FullNames)-1),Last,MID(FullNames,FIND(" ",FullNames)+1,99)))
/SUM(SUMIFS(Months,First,LEFT(FullNames,FIND(" ",FullNames)-1),Last,MID(FullNames,FIND(" ",FullNames)+1,99)))
```

If you need the name comparisons to be case insensitive then change FIND to SEARCH in the formula.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your formula works great. I have a follow up question: Why doesn't the formula work if I replace "Sales" with "Sales/Month" and get rid of the second SUM?

Comment: That's really the crux of this question. I faced a much more complicated problem at work, and changed it to a trivial sales table to illustrate the problem easier.

Comment: @KevinPresley The range arguments for SUMIFS (and related) have to be ranges.  Sales/Month is not a range, it is an array of the results of that operation.  I don't know what you mean by the `second SUM`.  The SUMIFS formula return an array of results. The SUM is required to add up the array elements.  SUM will accept an array as an argument.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I didn't know that. I was trying to give it a range divided by another range, or two ranges concatenated. I guess after a range is manipulated it becomes an array?

Comment: @KevinPresley Lookup the definition of `range` in the Excel glossary and you will see how it cannot refer to the results of an operation on two different ranges.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would've thought that I could use 'A1:A5 + B1:B5' in SUMIF, but it looks like I can only use 'A1:A5.' The addition converts a range to an array, and SUMIF can't take an array. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinPresley For those kinds of operations, look at `SUMPRODUCT`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result to be all in one cell, or in one cell per row?  If not, I am unsure why you are adding down a column (A1:A3).

As another note, if you are only avoiding computational cells/columns for appearance, you could put them on a separate sheet that is hidden.

*I would've added this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation.*

Comment: I would like for the results to be all in one cell. I am facing a more complex problem at work, but I made this trivial example to illustrate it. Basically I can't do any manipulation of the arrays within the formula. The main reason to avoid computational cells is not only neatness, but complexity. Since the formula will be applied to many different columns, it needs to be as small and compact as possible. Thank you for your answer!